# Enumerate with all lists as arabic numerals

Tags: enumerate

So apparently the suggestion in [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists#Ordered_lists) doesn't work in my document. I want that all enumerate and nested ones always uses arabic numerals, from 1,2,etc.

My preamble is this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Package for chemical equation typesetting                                                                                               
\usepackage{siunitx} % Provides the \SI{}{} and \si{} command for typesetting SI units                                                                                   
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for the inclusion of images                                                                                                             
\usepackage{amsmath} % Required for some math elements                                                                                                                   

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs                                                                                                      
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcommand{\comrem}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}.} % Make numbering in the enumerate environment by letter rather than number (e.g. section 6)                                    
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\Roman{enumii}}
```

Comment: Use the enumitem package, then it is very easy to setup. And please always post full examples, not useless sniplets

Comment: Your code stipulates that  firsdt level enumerate will use `a.`, `b.`, &c. and the second level will use `I`,`II`, &c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most convenient way to achieve this would be via [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `\setlist`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First nested
    \item Second nested
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First nested nested
      \item Second nested nested
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Third nested
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Second
  \item 
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First nested nested
      \item Second nested nested
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Final
\end{enumerate}

\setlist[enumerate]{label={\arabic*.}}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First nested
    \item Second nested
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First nested nested
      \item Second nested nested
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Third nested
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Second
  \item 
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First nested nested
      \item Second nested nested
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Final
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The first list (without any settings) displays the default settings for each (nested) list (level 1 = `\arabic`, level 2 = `(\alph*)`, level 3 = `\roman*.`):

[image]

The second list displays the updated settings, with each level set as `\arabic*.`:

[image]

Control over individual `<level>` formatting is also possible using

```
\setlist[enumerate,<level>]{<format spec>}
```

Your example code would use

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\alph*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\Roman*}}
```

---

If you plan on referencing list items, you may also consider specifying a separate `ref` key-value that doesn't use the trailing period `.`:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{label={\arabic*.}, ref={\arabic*}}
```