# Nested lists with roman numerals

Tags: lists, enumerate

I have seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54055/using-lower-case-roman-numerals-in-enumerate-lists) how roman numerals can be used in enumerate lists. How could I create nested lists with roman numerals, to get something like this?

```
(i) ...
    (i.i) ...
    (i.ii) ...
(ii) ...
```

Comment: Should not be too hard, but in case you didn't know the documentation is available on ctan

Comment: Do you want this to apply in one case or for the whole document?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enumerate with all lists as arabic numerals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527462/enumerate-with-all-lists-as-arabic-numerals)

Comment: @jessexknight just in one case

Comment: @jessexknight This one does not cover referring to `enumi` from the second level though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you mention that the roman-lowercase enumeration style is a one-off requirement for your document, I suggest you (a) load the `enumitem` package and (b) use its machinery to provide the formatting requirements as optional arguments to the respective instances of  `\begin{enumerate}`.

When creating cross-references to items in roman-enumerated lists, I suggest you omit the round parentheses. As the following example shows, the setup recommended in the preceding paragraph is sufficiently general/robust to allow the use of `\cref` directives to create cross-references.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % optional, for \cref macro

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),ref=\roman*]
\item \dots \label{list:1}
   \begin{enumerate}[label=(\theenumi.\roman*),ref=\theenumi.\roman*]
      \item \dots
      \item \dots \label{list:2.b}
   \end{enumerate}
\item \dots
\end{enumerate}

Cross-references to items \ref{list:1} and \ref{list:2.b}.

Cross-references to \cref{list:1,list:2.b}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Messing around a bit you can also do `\begin{enumerate}[ ref=\roman* , label=(\noexpand\theenumi) ]`. This is likely highly dependent on the exact implementation of the package though, so do not recommend (that noexpand is even necessary)

Answer (score 5):

Like this.

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman{enumi}.\roman*)}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 1
            \item 2
        \end{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 1
            \item 2
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Turns out the documentation is a bit lacking, for more complex operations it presupposes knowledge of the `enumerate` environment in LaTeX.
Read "printing counters" and "enumerate [environment]" chapter in LaTeX unofficial reference manual for details on `\roman` and `enumi`.

There's a similar example from the manual

[image: manual screenshot]

Comment: no code as text, neither page num

Comment: @SaveUkraine-StartPeaceTalk That is to show that "the manual contain the code" not "here is the code". The main part is in text anyway